# Can't log into server locally nor remotely

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I messed up when setting a group policy. Specifically the "Deny logon locally" in which i added the remote desktop group. I had enabled the forbid access through remote desktop as well and now i can't log in locally nor remotely (using the RD service). I thought that the administrator account could log at anything it wanted no matter what so i didn't really think much about it. Now i can't even log with the administrator account. I'm at a loss of what to do to access or reset the gpo remotely.

i tried this: gpedit.msc /gpcomputer:"computername" but it doesn't let me see the security policies.

Pretty embarrasing but... can someone please tell me how to solve this issue? thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it a local GPO only, with gpedit ? is the computer member of a domain ? if the computer is member of a domain, you can create a GPO with the correct configuration, in Active Directory, and target this computer.

Comment: I tried this but i couldn't access the security policies. I ended up solving the issue using a 3rd party program called Hyena.